# Fetching data in JSP on PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

When Try to fetching Data in database result it come zero row but when try to copy and past query on mysql has return specific number of rows needed.

---

### Connection to mysql server

---

```
private Connection connection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/olesdb", "root", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println("Connection error");
    }
    return con;
}
```

**

### My function for fetching data

**

```
public List<AcademicYearCourses> getStudentCourse(int studentID, int academicYear,int semester) throws SQLException{
    List<AcademicYearCourses> list = new ArrayList<>();
    PreparedStatement sta = connection().prepareStatement("SELECT courseCode,courseName FROM courses co,studentprograms stpro,academicyearcourse acco WHERE stpro.studentID=? AND acco.academicYearID=? AND acco.semesterID=? AND stpro.programID= acco.programID AND stpro.studyYear=acco.studyYear AND acco.courseID=co.courseID");
    sta.setInt(1, studentID);
    sta.setInt(2, academicYear);
    sta.setInt(3, semester);
    ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery();
    while(res.next()){
        AcademicYearCourses acco = new AcademicYearCourses();
        acco.setAcdemicYearCourseID(rs.getInt("acdemicYearCourseID"));
        acco.setCourseName(rs.getString("courseName"));
        acco.setCourseCode(rs.getString("courseCode"));
        list.add(acco);
    }
    return list;
}
```

So I need help to solve this issue it very important in my project and Cant continue without this data

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting this line `//System.out.println("Connection error");` to see if there is any exception?

Comment: Never catch an exception without handle it

Comment: `//System.out.println("Connection error");` this line is not problem because some function this class work

Comment: can you try `System.out.println(list.size());` before `return list;`

Comment: what it print?...

Comment: try also `System.out.println(sta.toString());` and tell us what query it print,

Comment: ok was but error come from field name in not found

Comment: `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@113e1f: SELECT courseName,courseCode FROM courses co,studentprograms stpro,academicyearcourse acco WHERE stpro.studentID=4 AND acco.academicYearID=1 AND acco.semesterID=1 AND stpro.programID= acco.programID AND stpro.studyYear=acco.studyYear AND acco.courseID=co.courseID`

Comment: Query it Ok but why???

Comment: Result After Add `System.out.println("Size "+list.size());` before return list;

Comment: what is the result?

Comment: Thank every one for help me to solve my error. I have get solution and now it work fine. Thank alot

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: `while(res.next()){ // here i use res as Result set
        AcademicYearCourses acco = new AcademicYearCourses();
        acco.setAcdemicYearCourseID(rs.getInt("acdemicYearCourseID")); // bur here i use rs as Resultset
        acco.setCourseName(rs.getString("courseName")); // bur here i use rs as Resultset
        acco.setCourseCode(rs.getString("courseCode")); // bur here i use rs as Resultset
        list.add(acco);
    }
    return list;`

Comment: ahh ok good luck

Comment: in the while i write `res` as Result set but  set value just write `rs` as Result set that problem

Comment: thank for your discussion I'm young developer in JSP so some error is not family with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are doing `rs.getInt("acdemicYearCourseID")` but column `acdemicYearCourseID` is not in your `SELECT` columns list.

Also try changing `getInt("...")`, `getString("...")` to `getInt(1),` `getString(2)`